# Is Noise filter needed for CAN passthrough?

Tags: can, emi-filtering, ferrite-bead, common-mode-choke

[image]

The structure is simply diagrammed as follow. My Board provides only routing connecting each connector for other ECUs using CAN channel.

My queistion is if i need additional CMCs on the routing. Are there other design considerations for noise filtering?

I just consider implementing ferrite bead if i see the ringing in the signal. Is it not enough?

Comment: So that board is virtually like cable cconnecting things together? Cables don't have ferrites or chokes anf they work between devices. Why would there be 3 to 4 ECUs on same bus? Also what would be the bus topology and where would the end terminators be?

Comment: How long are the cables between your "distributor board" and the ECUs?

Comment: CAN isn't made for a star topology...

Answer (score 2):

CAN bus is intended for electrically noisy environments. It's signalling interface is designed to be resilient to that noise. Its drivers into terminated loads produce little noise.

Your board is just an electrical connection. Any noise filtering filtering added to the CAN bus connections would not benefit the bus itself.

So filtering should not be done because it brings no electrical advantage.

From an engineering perspective, the filter components then just have all the disadvantages of adding any component to a board: extra cost, decreased reliability, possible procurement and obsolescence problems, another solder joint to fail etc.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying here - that CMCs shouldn't be added in the middle of the bus (left side of the picture) or you are saying that CMC shouldn't be used at all. The latter is not correct, they are very helpful in removing all manner of EMI. A correctly received frame is preferred over a discarded frame.

Comment: @Lundin, I'm saying something that I wouldn't now :-) I'd wrongly read the diagram as a backplane with three boards plugged in, hence the answer which is correct in that circumstance. I since realised that its cable connections of unknown length going to a junction box, which changes things. That may or may not be a reliable CAN bus arrangement - depends on the cable lengths and types, bus speed and electrical environment etc. If it is viable, filtering may be needed but again depending on cables/speed/environment.